# What's the right way to use a sparse matrix in scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression

I'm trying to accomplish a classification task trying to use a sparse matrix. When I pass my training set to the logistic regression function, in scikit, it returns this error:

```
ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

The type of the matrix I'm passing as argument to the logistic regression is `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`.

This is how I create the sparse matrix, from a numpy array with NaNs:

```
X=sparse.csr_matrix(X_hat)
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the same error with `train_test_split`, and these functions are supposed to accept sparse matrices as argument according to the documentation.

I'm using the version 0.14 of scikit-learn.

UPDATE:
This is the full TraceBack.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-acdaac419166> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 model2.fit(X_train, y_train)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    666                              " one.")
    667 
--> 668         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    669 
    670         self.class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(self.class_weight,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite)
    132     """
    133     return _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse.csr_matrix,
--> 134                                 "tocsr", force_all_finite)
    135 
    136 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse_class, convmethod, force_all_finite)
    105             X = sparse_class(X, dtype=dtype)
    106         if force_all_finite:
--> 107             _assert_all_finite(X.data)
    108         X.data = np.array(X.data, copy=False, order=order)
    109     else:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
     25     if (X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.sum())
     26             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
---> 27         raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
     28 
     29 

ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

Comment: The trick is not to use `nan`s as data or placeholders ... You can see if `X_hat=numpy.nan_to_num(X_hat)` works for your purpose. If not, you will have to do active work to replace the nans in an appropriate other way.

Comment: This work on my ndarray, mechanically, but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't need all my nans to be 0s.

Comment: What I don't understand is why logistic regression (and PCA and other functions) doesn't work with a sparse matrix when in the documentation is specified they do work with sparse matrices.

Comment: It doesn't work because your data contain `nan`s, not because the matrix is sparse, cf the `ValueError` message.

Comment: I see. I'm a bit confused on the meaning of sparse matrix then, I'll read more on it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need to. Just remove the nans and try again.

Comment: For "remove" you mean substitute the NaNs with meaningful values? Like 0s or big numbers depending on the feature?

Comment: exactly, substitute them with true numerical values of your (well reflected :)) choice.

Comment: A sparse matrix is just a matrix that has most values 0, and only the non-zero values are stored in memory. For NaNs: None of the algorithms in scikit-learn (except the imputers, which are to remove missing values) can work with NaN in a meaningful way. That is why they raise the error.